# A doubt about fuchsian functions in physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-geometry

I'm not sure if this is the right place (or math.stackexchange?) to ask the next

1. What is the difference between fuchsian, theta-fuchsian, and kleinian functions?
2. Please, suggest me an introductory reference to the Physics of previously asked for.